# Current Location in Google Maps using only a URL

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

So I would like to use a URL to retrieve and display ONLY the users CURRENT LOCATION.

For example: A user with a smartphone (iPhone, Android, etc) opens a link [http://maps.google.com/CURRENTLOCATION] on their phone, and it shows their current location on the user's device in either Google Maps app or browser, as reported by their GPS/wireless location. The actual link itself should should remain static, and display the location wherever they are.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to stalk someone?

Comment: Heh, No. I want the USER to click the link, and have that link display their current location on THEIR device. Question updated to reflect this. Thanks - you're right, that question does look a little suspect as it was originally worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed front and center in the Google Maps geolocation API: [Detecting the User's Location](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation)

According to the documentation, the user will need using an HTML5 equipped browser for this to work.  You will need to write the Javascript which looks pretty vanilla.

Edit: This only works if you are using your own domain and have implemented the Maps API (*which is really simple*), not Google's own *maps.google.com*

Answer (score 4):

If you have the lat/long coordinates (which I suppose you get through the gps/wireless device), you can use something like this:

http://maps.google.de/maps?q=loc:48.0000,9.000

which opens the Google Maps website with the coordinates N48.0 E9.0 (as decimal coords) centered.

Or, if you need a static map (and not a full fledged JavaScript map), use this link and adjust the values inside the URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.00,9.00&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|48.0,9.0&sensor=true

Valid values for the arguments are:

- for *maptype*: roadmap, terrain, satellite
- for zoom: 1 to 20

Comment: That's great, and thanks for the reply, but I need the link to automatically retrieve the location.

Comment: Ah, now I fully understand your question :). The answer from Jack is pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't solve the "URL only" portion to the question.  I don't believe there is any URL based solution.